# Can't control Skype Notifications volume on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype

I have Skype for Windows 10. There are no options to control the volume for notification sounds either in app or the Volume Mixer on Taskbar. What am I missing? Shouldn't the Volume Mixer show a volume controller for when a sound is played by the Skype app so that I can turn it down or up?

By the way, I can mute it from Settings, but I just wanna turn down the notification volume.

Thank you very much!

Comment: it might be using the system sound, so you could try to mute that (of course it will mute ALL system sounds) - if you have an ongoing call you should see skype in the volume mixer for the call.

Comment: No, this is not a solution. Sorry!

Comment: I never proposed it as a solution, just that you can try it and see if it is like that.

Answer (score 1):

> There are no options to control the volume for notification sounds
> either in app

Try the Settings in Skype.  There is an app volume control there as well as a Microphone Control.

That works here.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the setting for the communications device, the speakers, will control the volume of the notifications generated by Skype?

Comment: No, I have already tried that. It doesn't control it. I am sure this is a bug with Skype.

Comment: I have it working fine on 3 Windows machines. Uninstall Skype, restart, upgrade your audio driver, and install Skype again. Maybe try the Desktop version. The versions are very close.

Comment: You can turn off Notifications you do not need to receive. That may help you. Notifications are  a settings category below Audio..  Notifications are very granular.  Just a thought for you.

Comment: What you see in this screenshot doesn't control message notifications. Only in-call audio and maybe Skype call ringtone.